# How to solve exact pattern matching with convolution

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to solve an exact pattern matching problem when the alphabet consists of the 5 symbols {a, b, c, d, #} where the special symbol # matches any symbol (including itself).

For example, if T = ab#aca#ab#a and P = da#ac then P occurs starting at position 3 in T. I am trying to find a O(nlogn) time algorithm to determine whether a pattern P of length n occurs in a text T of length 2n, assuming that the # symbol occurs (possibly O(n) times) in T and P.

Any suggestions about how to solve it with convolution?

Comment: How big is your alphabet?  I know a pretty straightforward way to accomplish this that adds a factor proportional to the alphabet size to the time complexity, so it's pretty good for small alphabets (e.g. DNA).

Comment: I've just noticed an unaccept. Have you spotted something I have missed? If so, I would be interested to hear about it and learn from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can handle the problem, as stated, for arbitrary alphabet sizes, subject to floating point precision. For an alphabet of n characters, map the text characters to (complex) nth roots of unity. For the pattern characters, map # to 0, and map ordinary characters to the multiplicative inverse of the corresponding text character, and so also nth roots of unity.

You then use the convolution theorem to work out, at each point, the dot product of the text from that point on with the pattern. If the text and the pattern match, each component of the product is either 0 (at a wild card) or 1, from r*r^-1, so if you have a match the result will be m, where m is the number of non-wild card characters in the pattern. If there is not a match, then not all of the components of the dot product will be 1. Thinking of these complex numbers as 2-dimensional vectors, the dot product of these vectors with the vector representing 1 will be less than m, so a mismatch cannot cause a result m and look like a match.

I note that if you divide the text up into buffers of a few times the length of the pattern, you can use an FFT of that length reasonably efficiently, so the complexity is not n log n, where n is the length of the text to be searched, but n log m, where m is the length of the pattern. Despite that, I would need to see benchmark timings before I would believe that this is a competitive method, compared even with a naive search.

Answer (score 0):

The BNDM algorithm can cope with wildcard characters, [as this implementation shows](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/site/apidocs/com/eaio/stringsearch/BNDMWildcards.html), and meets your speed requirement in average case. However, it has O(nm) worst-case complexity.

Why exactly are you requiring convolution here?

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea of how to do it.

Calculate the cross-correlation function between T and P. It's done by convolving T and P. For long signals, convolution is most efficiently done through Fast Fourier Transform and it takes time proportional to N*log(N):

[Cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)
[Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)
[Fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

Then look for the maximum of the cross-correlation function. It will tell the position where T and P are aligned.

Convolution will have to handle "#" as a special case and, unless P is guaranteed to be found in T, this will have to be explicitly checked at the end.